# Replacing value in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm not sure how to replace a dictionary's value with another value. I want the value of `b` to be replaced by the value of `a`, and the value of `c` to be replaced by the value of `b` (which is the value of `a`).

```
my_dict = {"a":1, "b":"a", "c":"b"}
for d_values in my_dict.values():
   for d_keys in my_dict.keys(): 
      if d_keys in d_values:
          my_dict[d_keys] = d_values
```

I want `my_dict` to become `{a:1, b:1, c:1}`, but my code gives me `{a:a....}` somewhere along the line

Comment: In other words, you want all values to be replaced by the value at `a`.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you are over-complicating. Based on your requirement, what you simply want is

```
>>> dict.fromkeys(my_dict, my_dict['a'])
{'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1}
```

So instead of replacing the values, re-create the entire dictionary with the same key structure but with the value `my_dict['a']`

Answer (score 1):

> I want my_dict to become {a:1, b:1, c:1}, but my code gives me {a:a....} somewhere along the line

If you want to modify an existing dictionary, you can simply iterate over the elements setting all values in place:

```
>>> for e in my_dict.keys() : my_dict[e] = my_dict['a']
>>> print my_dict
{'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1}
```

Here I changed the keys to characters to make the example work.

Comment: changed my question to reflect what I want my dict values to look like

Answer (score 0):

If I got what you intend to do, this snipped does it:

```
my_dict = {"a":1, "b":"a", "c":"b"}

changed = True
while changed:
    changed = False
    for key, value in my_dict.items():
        if value in my_dict:
            changed = True
            my_dict[key] = my_dict[value]
```